# Prevent Joda-Time to print negative numbers

Tags: android, jodatime

I'm using following code to make my desired `String` but the negative sign would be printed if `Period` has passed. I'm going to show zero number instead of negative numbers only if `Period` is passed.

```
Period period = new Period(new LocalDateTime(System.currentTimeMillis(), DateTimeZone.forID("Iran")), new LocalDateTime(myEndTime, DateTimeZone.forID("Iran")), PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());

new PeriodFormatterBuilder().rejectSignedValues(true).printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendHours().appendSuffix(":").minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendMinutes().toFormatter().print(period);
```

**Note:** I'm using [Joda-Time](http://joda.org/joda-time/) inside of an Android app and JDKv7 is using.

Comment: Can you provide more code showing how you're computing the `period` variable?  Also, if you're using Java 8, have you considered using the built-in `java.time.*` APIs instead of Joda-Time?

Comment: @ck1 I updated my question. Java 8 is not suitable for developing Android app yet. JDK 7 is using.

Comment: @ck1 Alireza is right. And Java-8 does not support duration formatting, too.

Comment: The best you can do with Joda-Time here is not on the printing level (where you cannot avoid negative signs anywhere inside the formatted duration). Instead you could ask the `Period` before printing if it is negative or has a negative component. If yes then you could just call `negated()` on the `Period`-object and then print. But if you have mixed signs then you are lost with Joda-Time unless you manage to normalize your `Period` in a suitable way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @MenoHochschild.